# show only last updation of record in lead history report

Tags: reporting, leads, history-tracking

hi i am creating a lead history report, but got stuck in a problem. i want to show only last updation occurs to record rather than all updation of that record is their any way to do this. 
attached is the screen shot of my report

[image]

their is two sorting fields but all changes in last status updated by record, thanx in advance

Comment: Means you need to know only last update only @vishal chaudhary

Comment: yes like here in screenshot a record had multiple changes which is correct but i want to show only recent one as because currently all changes counts in same status which is recent updated status of record. is there any way to do this.

Comment: Create a new field called Last status edited and create a workflow like Ischanged(Status) and update above field.So,then you can use the field for reports. @vishal chaudhary

Comment: its still the same no effect,
let me upload the screenshot for you